# getting error #<TypeError: wrong argument type nil (expected Symbol)> when using binding.pry in rails 4

Tags: debugging, ruby-on-rails-4, binding.pry

getting this weird error

```
#<TypeError: wrong argument type nil (expected Symbol)>
```

in utf8_sanitizer

when doing `next` using `binding.pry` in **rails 4.2.1** with **ruby 2.2.0**

otherwise running without any error.

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this problem with some of my specs when I upgraded to Ruby 2.2  until I bumped byebug to 5.0.0 - not sure if it's the same since you didn't provide much description of your environment, but I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Had a similar issue with an error emanating from RouteSet - upgrading to 5.0.0 fixed.

Comment: I am having this issue again, with byebug 6.0.2 and MRI 2.2.2. Wonder if I should downgrade to byebug 5.x. Man.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading ByeBug resolved the issue for me as well:

```
bundle update byebug
```